# Display Array as List - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I have an array of scores in my iphone game. All I want is a plain list, just text of these scores.

Do I need to load this into a UITableView then somehow remove the background of the table, so it appears as just text, or is there a different method I can use to get this list as just text?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to better define what "as a list" means to you. You could construct a multiline string containing those values and disposing in a UILabel or UITextField but I can't tell if that would make sense for your data and your desired UI.

How many scores do you have? Will they all fit on the screen at one? Do you need to be able to scroll the list? Do you want to be able to tap on the scores? Copy them? Format them differently?

You certainly could also create a table view with a tranparent background on the table and it's cells. Just be aware that transparent cells are more expensive to render and will not scroll as smoothly as opaque cells.